# In Microsoft Remote Desktop, how can I change the account's password?

Tags: remote-desktop

I use Microsoft Remote Desktop, in there, before I set an account `103.231.8.185\root`.

[image]

[image]

Now, the server `103.231.8.185`'s password has been changed, how can I change the account's password in this software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this password is stored in [Keychain Access](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/what-is-keychain-access-kyca1083/mac)